# Why does a user who has direct edit privileges have to vote for approving suggested edits?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

I have come across something strange: I have direct edit privileges on Stack Overflow, that is, I can make edits without having my edits approved from other users. Though, when I come to approving edits made by other users, I can only *vote* for the edit to be approved, then wait for another vote for the edit to take place. I am wondering, what is the logic behind this? I can make edits myself, but can't approve other edits? One would simply think of rejecting that edit and making their own.

Comment: There is a good answer to this here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29700/why-we-need-more-than-one-review-to-accept-an-edit